# An example of an $m$-primary ideal in noetherian local domain

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is there any example of a $m$-primary ideal $I$ in a noetherian local domain $(R, m)$ such that $I^2=mI\not=m^2 $?

Comment: A related post on MathOverflow: [Square of primary ideals](https://mathoverflow.net/q/149713).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example: Take $R = \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z,w]_{(x,y,z,w)}/(x^2-zw, z^2-yw, y^3-xw, w^3-xy^2z)$. One can check (e.g. in [Macaulay2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/)) that $R$ is a domain (with $\dim R = 1$). Let $m = (x,y,z,w)$ be the maximal ideal, and set $I = (x,y,z)$. Then the first $3$ relations in $R$ guarantee that $I^2 = mI$, while the last relation gives that $w^3 \in I^2$, so $m^3 \subseteq I$ and $I$ is $m$-primary, but in fact $w^2 \in m^2 \setminus I^2$.

Comment: Very interesting example. One also sees $m^3 = m^2I$. How did you come up with the example?

Comment: @Youngsu: I just played around in Macaulay2 for a bit. It was natural to try an ideal $I$ which had one less generator than $m$, and then take a minimal prime over the ideal obtained by forcing products of that generator with the ones in $I$ to be in $I^2$. The key point is to ensure that $m^2 \ne mI$ after quotienting, which happened to work in this example because of the exponent $3$